# JSoup POST authentication

Tags: java, post, authentication, jsoup

I'm trying to connect to a site with basic username & password authentication, keep the cookies and parse data from a site that requires the cookies given at the login-page. The parsing works perfect when using a copy of the website from a local Apache webserver. It's the authentication that's giving me trouble. I'm using Eclipse as my IDE and I keep getting an error with the following piece of code:

```
    Response res = Jsoup
        .connect("site_with_login")
        .data("login", "MyUsername")
        .data("pass", "MyPassword")
        .method(Method.POST)
        .execute();

    //Keep logged in
    Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();
```

The `.method(Method.POST)` is the problem, because the error is at `POST`. Here's the output when running the parsing:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
POST cannot be resolved or is not a field

at parseHTML.main(parseHTML.java:26)
```

It's strange, because a lot of posts here on stackoverflow mention that excact way to authenticating. I have imported all the packaged and have the jsoup-1.7.2.jar file in my library.

Does anyone know how I can solve this annoying problem?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: 
I'm currently using the following packages:

```
    import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;
    import org.jsoup.Connection;
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.Response;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
    import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
```

The whole block of code I posted now gives the following error:

```
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from Connection.Response to HttpConnection.Response
```

[The whole code is available here](http://pastebin.com/AbG8YB8V)

Comment: Please add the full code. Its hard to help without the context...

Comment: I added it as a pastebin link, it seemed easier.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using a wrong import.

Make sure you use:

```
.method(Connection.Method.POST)
```

Make sure you import:
`org.jsoup.Connection.Method` and not `java.lang.reflect.Method`

Another import issue:

`import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;`

instead of:

```
import org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.Response;
```

Comment: please add it to the question

Comment: So it did help? but you get a new problem?

Comment: Yes, it did remove the errors Eclipse gave me, but the code is not printing the expected output :(

Comment: I'm getting a <terminated> message in the console instead of the output I'm getting when using a site running from localhost.

Comment: I'm pretty new to java and programming in general, how would I debug my code? Is there something like LogCat for plain java?